Web application using Rafael JS crashes on Safari and Chrome after updating to iOS 18.2
After updating my phone to iOS 18.2 2 days ago, I noticed that a website I'm working on that uses Rafael JS(https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael) to do some svg rendering which used to work before I updated just stopped working. I am also using this library for importing svg into Rafael: (rafael-svg-import)
I notice that Safari tries to load website tries to load 2 or 3 times before showing the error: A problem repeatedly occurred on  which I find really odd since this used to work before and I haven't made any changes to the code.
This also happens in Chrome on iOS 18.2.

if you update to snap.svg instead (it's pretty much compatible with Raphael, but would need some tweaks), does it work ok ?

On our application we are getting customer complaints since last week with an issue that looks similar to yours. Page loads fine, then refreshes after a couple of seconds, and then refreshes again before showing a browser error. Having this issue on both Chrome and Safari on iOS. Did you figure out what was the root cause?

our issue appeared to be caused by microsoft's clarity.js loading very slowly. removing clarity.js fixed things for us.

Nice find! We are using MS Clarity as well and removing it seems to solve our issue!
